# cp command to exclude certain files from being copied

Tags: command-line, bash, cp

Is there a way to use the `cp` command to copy a directory and exclude certain files/sub-directories within it?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use `rsync`:

```
rsync -av --exclude='path1/to/exclude' --exclude='path2/to/exclude' source destination
```

Note that using `source` and `source/` are different. A trailing slash means to copy the **contents** of the folder `source` into `destination`. Without the trailing slash, it means copy the folder source into `destination`.

Alternatively, if you have lots of directories (or files) to exclude, you can use `--exclude-from=FILE`, where `FILE` is the name of a file containing files or directories to exclude.

`-av` means archive mode and verbose.

`--exclude` may also contain wildcards, such as `--exclude=*/.svn*`.

**Copied From:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/2194500/749232

If you want to use `cp` itself:

```
find . -type f -not -iname '*/not-from-here/*' -exec cp '{}' '/dest/{}' ';'
```

This assumes the target directory structure is the same as the source's.

**Copied From:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/4586025/749232

Comment: The word "contents" in "copy the contents of the folder..." is a major keyword to understand the sentence. It should be bolded and highlighted.

Answer (score 13):

Late into the game but here is a very different solution using plain Bash and `cp`: you can use a global file specification while having some files ignored.

Assume the directory contains the files:

```
$ ls *
listed1  listed2  listed3  listed4  unlisted1  unlisted2  unlisted3
```

Using the [GLOBIGNORE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) variable:

```
$ export GLOBIGNORE='unlisted*'
$ ls *
listed1  listed2  listed3  listed4
```

Or with more specific exclusions:

```
$ export GLOBIGNORE='unlisted1:unlisted2'
$ ls *
listed1  listed2  listed3  listed4  unlisted3
```

Or using [negative matches](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
$ ls !(unlisted*)
listed1  listed2  listed3  listed4
```

This also supports several unmatched patterns:

```
$ ls !(unlisted1|unlisted2)
listed1  listed2  listed3  listed4  unlisted3
```

Comment: For negative matches you need to have extended globs enabled: `shopt -s extglob`, also you don't need to export `GLOBIGNORE`: it's supposed to modify the behaviour of the current shell, most child programs wouldn't care about it.

Comment: BTW, to turn off extended glob, run `shopt -u extglob`.

Answer (score 4):

#### Quick Start

Run:

```
rsync -av --exclude='path1/in/source' --exclude='path2/in/source' [source]/ [destination]
```

---

#### Notes

- `-avr` will create a new directory named `[destination]`.
- `source` and `source/` create different results:

  - `source/` — copy the *contents* of source into destination.
  - `source` — copy the *folder* source into destination.
- To exclude many files:

  - `--exclude-from=FILE` — `FILE` is the name of a file containing other files or directories to exclude.
- `--exclude` may also contain wildcards:

  - e.g. `--exclude=*/.svn*`

Modified from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2194500/749232

---

#### Example

Starting folder structure:

```
.
├── destination
└── source
    ├── fileToCopy.rtf
    └── fileToExclude.rtf
```

Run:

```
rsync -av --exclude='fileToExclude.rtf' source/ destination
```

Ending folder structure:

```
.
├── destination
│   └── fileToCopy.rtf
└── source
    ├── fileToCopy.rtf
    └── fileToExclude.rtf
```

Comment: I generally use -avh --progress as a rule, add --ignore-existing if copying to a destination that gets regular backups and want to skip files that match created/modified time and size, and add --delete-after if deleted files in source and destination should reflect those deletions. -z is compression and can help make the transfer a little faster if backing up to a remote location (fairly unnecessary on LAN).  --bwlimit=10000 (rate given in KB/s) will limit speed to 10MB/s and is helpful for long backup if concerned about hampering total bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cp` with the `!` character.

For example, to exclude the file or files `file.txt`, `test.jpg` and the directory `nodir`, while copying all others from the `source` directory to the `destination` directory, you may run:

```
cp source/!(file.txt|test.jpg|nodir) destination
```

If you have, for example, a file structure as this one:

```
.
├── destination
└── source
    ├── file.rtf
    ├── file.txt
    ├── test.jpg
    ├── yes
    |    └── test.jpg 
    └── nodir
         └── other.jpg
```

The result after running the above command is:

```
.
└── source (not modified)
└── destination
    ├── file.rtf
    └── yes
         └── test.jpg
```

Here is an article with information on `rsync` and `cp` with exclude: [How to cp copy and exclude internal files or directories (equivalent to rsync –exclude)](https://blog.desdelinux.net/en/how-to-copy-with-cp-and-exclude-files-or-internal-directories-equivalent-to-rsync-exclude/)

Comment: if you use this script in bash file, add 
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob for remove error on (

Answer (score 0):

Everyone seems to answering with "Use rsync", while I agree that is a very powerful tool its also overkill and presents some risks. The OP asked how to do it with `cp` and I found this worked combining some of the recommendations others made.

`cp -rf !(backup) backup/`

This was a simple experiment in copying all the files in a directory to a file called backup in the same directory without `cp` worrying about skipping a recursive call. Hope this helps.